# Can't send email to Gmail accounts

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, email, gmail

I'm trying to send an email to a Gmail account, but I get an error saying that the Header is lacking From.
When I add From to the header I get an error saying there's multiple From values in the header. (...?)

Code without From in header:

```
public MimeMessage AsMimeMessage()
{
    MimeMessage result = new MimeMessage();
    result.Subject = this.Subject;
    result.Sender = MailboxAddress.Parse(this.Sender);

    foreach (string str in this.Receivers)
    {
        result.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(str));
    }

    foreach (string str in this.CC)
    {
        result.Cc.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(str));
    }

    foreach (string str in this.BCC)
    {
        result.Bcc.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(str));
    }

    BodyBuilder body = new BodyBuilder();
    body.HtmlBody = this.HtmlBody;

    foreach (string path in _attachments)
    {
        body.Attachments.Add(path);
    }

    result.Body = body.ToMessageBody();

    return result;
}
```

Then I get:

> Messages missing a valid address in From: header, or 550 5.7.1 having
> no From: header, are not accepted.

If I add From in header:

```
public MimeMessage AsMimeMessage()
{
    MimeMessage result = new MimeMessage();
    result.Subject = this.Subject;
    result.Sender = MailboxAddress.Parse(this.Sender);

    foreach (string str in this.Receivers)
    {
        result.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(str));
    }

    foreach (string str in this.CC)
    {
        result.Cc.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(str));
    }

    foreach (string str in this.BCC)
    {
        result.Bcc.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse(str));
    }

    BodyBuilder body = new BodyBuilder();
    body.HtmlBody = this.HtmlBody;

    foreach (string path in _attachments)
    {
        body.Attachments.Add(path);
    }

    result.Headers.Add("From", this.FromName);
    result.Body = body.ToMessageBody();

    return result;
}
```

I get:

> This message is not RFC 5322 compliant. There are multiple From
> 550-5.7.1 headers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: And that's only happening if the receipient is Gmail? Or always?

Comment: @Fildor yes only Gmail accounts, it works fine when sending to other adresses

Answer (score 1):

You should add the from clause this way

```
result.From.Add (new MailboxAddress ("", this.FromName));
```

Comment: thanks! it almost did the trick, just had to change Sender and From as you said

Comment: it is hard to guess, with out seeeing the actual data

Comment: This could be vastly improved by explaining WHY this works.

Answer (score 0):

I changed

```
result.Sender = MailboxAddress.Parse(this.Sender);
```

to

```
result.Sender = new MailboxAddress(this.FromName, this.Sender);
```

and

```
result.Headers.Add("From", this.FromName);
```

to

```
result.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(this.FromName, this.Sender));
```

and it works!